# Xunit Skip Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, skip

can you tell me if it is possible to somehow skip test execution depending on the value of a Boolean variable in the json file, the skip attribute is not tied to the condition, and reflection does not see this attribute, just if-return does not suitable.

I need the test not to even run, so it doesn’t suit me if it simply returns successful execution (without executing the body)

Skip attribute,
If-Return in body of test
Reflection

Skip tests depending on the value of a boolean variable but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know xUnit does not provide built-in solution for this **currently**. But there are 3rd party libraries like [`Xunit.SkippableFact`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.SkippableFact/) which allows you to skip certain tests during runtime if some conditions met.

```
[SkippableFact]
public void Given_When_Then()
{
    Skip.If(EvaluateYourDynamicCondition(), "It is skipped based xyz.json");

    // Arrange
    // ...

}
```

`SkippableTheory` is also supported if you are using parameterized unit tests (PUT).

---

**UPDATE #1**

In case of xUnit V3, which is [not released](https://xunit.net/docs/v3-alpha) at the time of writing, will [support](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/SkipAsserts.cs) dynamic skipability.

```
[Fact]
public void Given_When_Then()
{
    Assert.SkipWhen(EvaluateYourDynamicCondition(), "It is skipped based xyz.json");

    // Arrange
    // ...

}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

> This library does not work as I need, tests are still executed, they just throw exceptions

It does work for me.

[image: skippeableFact]

Comment: maybe there is a way to do something similar yourself without third-party libraries, perhaps using trait, or I don’t know, using your own attributes, etc??

Comment: @user384884 if it would be easy to solve this problem via inheritance and/or attributes then xunit v3 and the 3rd party library would expose this functionality via that way.

Comment: This library does not work as I need, tests are still executed, they just throw exceptions

Comment: @user384884 It should work without any extra setup. I've updated the post to show you it works like a charm.